# How to get IRandomAccessStreamReference from image resource?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working with a Map view in a UWP application.

I want to initialize a Map icon (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapIcon) using an image. The image file is stored as a resource in my project. The MapIcon object contains an Image property, which is of type "IRandomAccessStreamReference".

How do I create an IRandomAccessStreamReference from the image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/MyImage.png"))
```